# Python lmfit impose subtle constraints

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, lmfit

I'm dealing with the following question:

```
d1=-1/b1*log((p1*t-a1)/c1)
d2=-1/b2*log((p2*t-a2)/c2)
d3=-1/b3*log((p3*t-a3)/c3)
```

where `a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3,p1,p2,p3` are known, and theoretically `d1=d2=d3>0`, so I try to find the proper `t` to minimize `(d1-d2)^2+(d2-d3)^2+(d3-d1)^2`. I try to use lmfit to do it, but don't know to impose the restrictions like `d>0` and the thing in log is greater than 0, namely `(p*t-a)/c>0`. [There are simple examples in lmfit's document](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/constraints.html), in my case I don't know how to do. Can anybody helps? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the values of `b1`,  `b2`,  `b3`, `c1`,  `c2`,  `c3`, you can place bounds on the value of `t` so that `d1>0`.   If `b1` is positive, 
`d1>0` means that `log((p1*t-a1)/c1)` > 0, so that the argument to the log function  is **greater than 1** (not only "greater than 0").  That means `p1*t-a1 > c1` or  `t > (c1 + a1)/p1`, and so on.  So, you can create a Parameter for `t` and set its minimum value to be the largest of `[(c1+a1)/p1, (c2+a2)/p2, (c3+a3)/p3]` to satisfy `d1,d2,d3>0`.